# How do I convert a text corpus into a string? gettign error code: expected str instance, list found

Tags: python, pandas, string, matplotlib, gensim

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv06W.png)

Getting the error code: word_frequency = Counter(" ".join(description_list).split()).most_common(10)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

What am I doing wrong? I have attempted to convert the text corpus into string to no avail. How do I bypass this error? Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code?

CODE:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
from re import X
import string
from tokenize import Token
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-61294585"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()   

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

document = text 

text_corpus = [text]

# Create a set of frequent words
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split(' '))
# Lowercase each document, split it by white space and filter out stopwords
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist]
         for document in text_corpus]

# Count word frequencies
from collections import defaultdict
frequency = defaultdict(int)
for text in texts:
    for token in text:
        frequency[token] += 1

# Only keep words that appear more than once
processed_corpus = [[token for token in text if frequency[token] > 1] for text in texts]
pprint.pprint(processed_corpus)

data = {
    "description": [text_corpus]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
description_list = df['description'].values.tolist()

text = ','.join(map(str, description_list))
word_frequency = Counter(" ".join(description_list).split()).most_common(10)

# `most_common` returns a list of (word, count) tuples
words = [word for word, _ in word_frequency]
counts = [counts for _, counts in word_frequency]

plt.bar(words, counts)
plt.title("10 most frequent tokens in description")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.xlabel("Words")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array like this : `[[]]`

so use `description_list[0]` instead of `description_list`

`word_frequency = Counter(" ".join(description_list[0]).split()).most_common(10)`